# Reload UICollectionViewCell from within cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage, uicollectionreusableview

What is the best way to retry a failed image download in cellForItemAtIndexPath? I have a collection view that can show about 20 80x80 thumbnail images. I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to download and cache images in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, but I've found that every so often an image fails to download. I know I can use a completion block and test if the image is nil, but it doesn't seem to be reloading the image correctly (the image still never shows up). Is this how I should be handling reloading the cell? Here's an example of my code.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
    NSURL *thumbnailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    INCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:thumbnailURL completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
        if (!image) {
            [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
        }
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer on [github](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/465#issuecomment-23033595)

> You need to use one of the methods with an "options" parameter and
>   specify SDWebImageRetryFailed like so...
>
> [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:thumbnailURL placeholderImage:[UIImage
>   imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] options:SDWebImageRetryFailed
>   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType
>   cacheType) {...}];